# MY app doesn't run in android studio although there is no errors , what i suppose to do?

Tags: java, android-studio

that's what it  gives me when i run it on debug LGOGCAT 
01-26 17:50:17.429 2714-2714/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-26 17:50:17.516 2714-2714/com.example.android.seif W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.android.seif-1/lib/arm64
01-26 17:50:17.634 2714-2714/com.example.android.seif W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
01-26 17:50:17.721 2714-2714/com.example.android.seif I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
01-26 17:50:17.722 2714-2714/com.example.android.seif I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
01-26 17:50:18.239 2714-2714/com.example.android.seif I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2714 SIG: 9

> xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Team A"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="56sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:onClick="addThreeForTeamA"
                android:text="3points" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:onClick="addTwoForTeamA"
                android:text="2points" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:onClick="addOneForTeamA"
                android:text="1points" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <view
            android:layout_width="0.1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

        </view>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Team B"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="56sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:onClick="addThreeForTeamB"
                android:text="3points" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:onClick="addTwoForTeamB"
                android:text="2points" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:onClick="addOneForTeamB"
                android:text="1points" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:onClick="resetScore"
        android:text="Reset" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> java

```
package com.example.android.seif;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int scoreTeamA = 0;
    int scoreTeamB = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void addThreeForTeamA(View view) {
        scoreTeamA = scoreTeamA + 3;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
    }

    public void addTwoForTeamA(View view) {
        scoreTeamA = scoreTeamA + 2;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);

    }

    public void addOneForTeamA(View view) {
        scoreTeamA = scoreTeamA + 1;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
    }

    public void addThreeForTeamB(View view) {
        scoreTeamB = scoreTeamB + 3;
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
    }

    public void addTwoForTeamB(View view) {
        scoreTeamB = scoreTeamB + 2;
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);

    }

    public void addOneForTeamB(View view) {
        scoreTeamB = scoreTeamB + 1;
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
    }

    public void resetScore(View view) {
        scoreTeamA = 0;
        scoreTeamB = 0;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
    }


    public void displayForTeamA(int score) {
        TextView scoreView = findViewById(R.id.team_a_score);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }

    public void displayForTeamB(int score) {
        TextView scoreView = findViewById(R.id.team_b_score);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }
```

}

Comment: Can u show us the `AndroidManifest` file?